# Rotating a graphic using arc2d

Tags: java, graphics, paint, graphics2d

i am trying to do a roulette casino game, so for this i made my roulette using the Arc2D package.

**My code below**

```
package roulette;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class RouletteInterface extends JPanel{
    public int spinValue = 0;
    public void paint(Graphics g){       
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        paintRoulette(g2d);

    }

    public void paintRoulette(Graphics2D g2d) {
        RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(10, 10);
        at.rotate(spinValue, 10, 10);


        double angle = 360 / 36.9;
        double startAngle = 0;
        int color = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                if(color == 0) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    color = 1;
                } else {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    color = 0;
                }
            }

            g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(100, 100, 300, 300, startAngle, angle, Arc2D.PIE));
            startAngle += angle;
        }

        g2d.transform(at);

        Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                spinValue += 0.01;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

In short i am not using a generalpath because i want to fill each arc with color red/green or black like the original roulette, and for the rotation i tried using a timer to increase the spinValue (this worked for me but when i use a generalpath) for the AfinneTransformation, but when i run the code, well, nothing happens. It shows me only the roulette without animation. What can i do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be trying to setup the timer in the paint method, as this going to get called, like, all the time. You should be overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and you should be creating a copy of the `Graphics` context before applying transformations as this will seriously mess up future updates

Comment: Also, paint happens in serial, so each operation will effect the next operation, this means, your transformation needs to happen BEFORE you paint what you want transformed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting and graphics in general are quite advanced topics, Java/Swing does a good job to "commonalise" the APIs into something which is reasonable easy to use, but still takes time and effort to learn and understand fully.

I would highly recommend having [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) and the JavaDocs booked marked, as you will be coming back to them on a regular bases (I still do)

There are lots of issues, which are compounding to make your life difficult.

Starting with...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){       
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    paintRoulette(g2d);

}
```

You should favour overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, paint is a complicated process and you need to choose your entry point into carefully.  Also, you should always call the paint methods `super` method, unless you are absolutely, positively prepared to take over its core functionality yourself.

In your case, you should also be making a copy of the `Graphics` context before passing it to `paintRoulette`, as `Graphics` is a shared resource and the transformations you are applying will cause issues for anything which is painted after your component.

Transformations...

```
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(10, 10);
at.rotate(spinValue, 10, 10);
```

This is somewhat interesting.  You're creating translation of `10x10` which will move the origin point of the `Graphics` context.  You then apply a rotation, which is anchored to `10x10`.

The reason I mention it is because you then do...

```
g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(100, 100, 300, 300, startAngle, angle, Arc2D.PIE));
```

This means that the arc is offset by `110x110` from the corner of the component (add in your translation) and you'll be rotating about a point `20x20` from the component's top/left corner (add in your translation) ... this is weird to me because the centre of the of wheel is actually at `250x250` (from the component's top/left corner) which is going to make for one very weird affect.

Finally, you apply the transformation AFTER the painting is done AND then create a `Timer` inside the paint method...

Painting is done in serial.  So one operation will effect the next, this will mean you will need to apply the transformation BEFORE you paint something (that you want transformed)

You also need to understand that you don't control the paint process, this means that your component may be painted for any number of reason at any time without your interaction.  This means you could an infinite number of `Timer`s, over a very small period of time.

Instead, your timer should be controlled externally from the `paint` process.

One other thing that took me some time to work out is...

```
public int spinValue = 0;
//...
Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        spinValue += 0.01;
        repaint();
    }
});
```

You declare `spinValue` as `int`, but are adding a floating point value to it, this will have the effect of the decimal component been truncated, so the value will ALWAYS be `0`.

Also, `AffineTransform#rotate` expects angles to be in radians, not degrees.  Not sure if it's important, but you should be aware of it.

## Runnable example...

Okay, so after applying the above, the code "might" look something like...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new RoulettePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class RoulettePane extends JPanel {

        private double spinValue = 0;
        private Timer timer;

        public RoulettePane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    spin();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            paintRoulette(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void spin() {
            if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    spinValue += 0.01;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void paintRoulette(Graphics2D g2d) {
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            int dimeter = Math.min(width, height);

            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(spinValue, dimeter / 2, dimeter / 2);
            g2d.transform(at);

            double angle = 360 / 36.9;
            double startAngle = 0;
            int color = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    if (color == 0) {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        color = 1;
                    } else {
                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        color = 0;
                    }
                }

                g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, dimeter, dimeter, startAngle, angle, Arc2D.PIE));
                startAngle += angle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*nb:* I took the translation out for the time been as I wanted to focus on making the output more dynamic based on the actual width/height of the component

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another question, what should i use to program the ball, the timer stops and the ball "falls" in a random arc giving me a number, what can i use for that? (I know how to stop the timer but i don't know how to "set" and/or "get" a number to the arcs.)